# GLSL issue with smoothstep function where edge0 is bigger than edge1

Tags: glsl, smoothstep

I'm learning GLSL language in the book of shaders site. And at page 5, I see the following code.

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform vec2 u_mouse;
uniform float u_time;

// Plot a line on Y using a value between 0.0-1.0
float plot(vec2 st) {    
    return smoothstep(0.02, 0.0, abs(st.y - st.x));
}

void main() {
    vec2 st = gl_FragCoord.xy/u_resolution;

    float y = st.x;

    vec3 color = vec3(y);

    // Plot a line
    float pct = plot(st);
    color = (1.0-pct)*color+pct*vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
}
```

Basically the code result is a gradient from white to black and a green line from bottom left to top right. I understand where the black gradient come from. But I don't understand something about the smoothstep function where the edge0 is bigger than the edge1. I tried to change the value of `abs(st.y - st.x)` to any float positive number example 0.01. It's supposed to return a value around 0.5 if I understand it correctly. But somehow the returned value is always 0.0, because the green line is gone. Can anyone help me understand how the smoothstep function work?

Answer (score 2):

This code is broken. In GLSL 4.40 for example, the result is undefined ([spec](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.40.pdf)):

> ```
> genType smoothstep (genType edge0, genType edge1, genType x)
> ```
>
> Returns 0.0 if `x <= edge0` and 1.0 if `x >= edge1` and
> performs smooth Hermite interpolation between 0 and 1
> when `edge0 < x < edge1`. This is useful in cases where
> you would want a threshold function with a smooth
> transition. This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> genType t;
> t = clamp ((x – edge0) / (edge1 – edge0), 0, 1);
> return t * t * (3 – 2 * t);
> ```
>
> (And similarly for doubles.)
>
> *Results are undefined if `edge0 >= edge1`.*

In GLSL 1.10, the result wasn't *explicitly* undefined, so presumably this last sentence was added in some later revision.